# Display tabular mbean attribute in tabular form

Tags: java, jmx, visualvm, mbeans, jmc

I have an MBean that has an attribute that is `TabularType` of a `CompositeType`, basically a table of rows. I would like to have this displayed as a table of rows in either VisualVM or Java Mission Control.

VisualVM (with the MBeans plugin) shows only a single row at a time and one has to navigate by clicking right or left.

Java Mission Control displays the rows as key value pairs

1. row 1

   - attribute 1 value 1.1
   - attribute 2 value 1.2
   - attribute 3 value 1.3
2. row 2

   - attribute 1 value 2.1
   - attribute 2 value 2.2
   - attribute 3 value 2.3

rather than as a table.

Can the display options of either be changed so that the attribute is displayed as a table like this?

| attribute 1 | attribute 2 | attribute 3 |

| value 1.1 | value 1.2 | value 1.3 |

| value 2.1 | value 2.2 | value 2.3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMC can't display TabularType as a table.